# Send file/image as a message from local system in Microsoft Team Channel

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

How can I send the local file/image in Microsoft Teams Channel using Send Message of  Microsoft Graph API?

I have followed a document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/chatmessageattachment?view=graph-rest-1.0 to attach an image when creating a message to send the team channel. I am trying to send the base64 format of an image. But I am getting an error.

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "InternalServerError",
        "message": "Failed to process request.",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2020-09-25T11:43:02",
            "request-id": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
            "client-request-id": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can send file attachments using graph API. Could you please check this [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chatmessage-post?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http#example-4-file-attachments)?

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is no appropriate API for you to send local file as message directly.

[`Creating chatMessage in a channel`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-post-messages?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) just supports send the file that has been in SharePoint. So, there are two steps to send the local file: first, upload file to SharePoint, then create chatMessage.

---

**1. Upload file to SharePoint:**

File smaller than 4MB:

```
PUT https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/{{drive-id}}/items/root:/{{file-name}}:/content
Header:
"Authorization" : "Bearer <access-token>"
Body: binary (select binary option in body in postman)
Upload a file using select file option
file-name: is file name along with extension example: test.txt
```

File greater than 4MB:

```
GET: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/{{drive-id}}/items/root:/{{file-name}}:/createUploadSession
Header:
"Authorization" : "Bearer <access-token>"
```

The Get request will return upload url.

```
PUT <upload url>
Header:
"Authorization" : "Bearer <access-token>"
Body: binary (select binary option in body in postman)
```

For more details, see [here](https://medium.com/@rahul.metangale/upload-a-file-to-sharepoint-using-azure-graph-api-9deacce57449).

**2. Create chatMessage:**

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/{id}/channels/{id}/messages
Content-type: application/json

{
    "body": {
        "contentType": "html",
        "content": "Here's the latest budget. <attachment id=\"153fa47d-18c9-4179-be08-9879815a9f90\"></attachment>"
    },
    "attachments": [
        {
            "id": "153fa47d-18c9-4179-be08-9879815a9f90",
            "contentType": "reference",
            "contentUrl": "https://m365x987948.sharepoint.com/sites/test/Shared%20Documents/General/test%20doc.docx",
            "name": "Budget.docx"
        }
    ]
}
```